# What is the sequence of the main spacecraft and CubeSats separation during Falcon 9 launch?

Tags: launch, rockets, falcon-9, cubesat, launch-sequence

I'm curious about timeline and the procedures related to the spacecraft separation during Falcon 9 (and perhaps other rockets if such information is available) launch.

Let's assume a mission with one major satellite to LEO (SSO) and number of piggyback CubeSats. I assume that they are deployed after the main payload separation. But does the upper stage change its orbit before or after the deployment? Are the CubeSats deployed all at once or sequentially?

Comment: Individual missions may vary, here is one example: http://space.stackexchange.com/a/16666/12102

Comment: Only a small number of Falcon 9 flights have carried cubesats (ISS cargo payloads excluded) and for those the sequencing has varied considerably.

Comment: @pericynthion can you name any rocket for which that statement is **not** true?